# Noob Issue with Activate.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, createinstance

I am working on being able to dynamically invoke an instantiation of a class dynamically at run time.

I have spent the better part of this morning searching Google for an answer but I am pretty green in this world so I am sure the answers make sense, but they do not to me.

```
public class MSD : IGBRule
{
    public MSD(GoverningBodyRulesGet_Result GBRule, int UserID)
    {}
```

The line error and the error are both below

```
object v = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("RulesEngine.Rules.MSD, RulesEngine.Rules"), UserID, GBRules);
```

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Constructor on type 'RulesEngine.Rules.MSD' not found.'

Comment: It looks like you are passing arguments to `CreateInstance` in wrong order

Comment: The arguments you're passing are in the order user ID, rules - but the constructor has the parameters in the opposite order. (I'd *strongly* advise you to reconsider the naming of all of this, by the way.)

Comment: Frankly I'd advise *against* using this type of construction - there are lots of ways this can end badly. IMO, if you're going to need to construct something via reflection, aim for a public parameterless constructor, perhaps dealing with anything else *after* construction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an object and pass arguments to the constructor, you will have to provide the arguments in the correct order, matching the order you have specified in your constructor. So in your case, you want to pass the rule before the user id:

```
var type = Type.GetType("RulesEngine.Rules.MSD, RulesEngine.Rules");
object v = Activator.CreateInstance(type, GBRules, UserID);
```

If you pass the constructor arguments directly to the `CreateInstance` method, you will have to be careful with common types as it is possible that you are accidentally selecting a [different overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance) that doesn’t call the correct constructor. You can avoid that by passing an object array with the arguments you want to pass:

```
var type = Type.GetType("RulesEngine.Rules.MSD, RulesEngine.Rules");
object[] args = new object[] { GBRules, UserID };
object v = Activator.CreateInstance(type, args);
```

Comment: "you will need to pass an object array with the arguments you want to pass" - not quite true; there is a `Type, params object[]` overload for `Activator.CreateInstance`, so **just** swapping the order is sufficient, i.e. `Activator.CreateInstance(..., GBRules, UserID);` - the key thing here is: the order